# Create get SVG file contents from SVG raw data and download it

Tags: php, laravel

I have SVG raw data such like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="100px" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 100 100"><defs><rect id="r0" width="3" height="3" fill="#000000"/></defs><rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="#fefefe"/><use x="12" y="12" xlink:href="#r0"/><use x="15" y="12" xlink:href="#r0"/><use x="18" y="12" xlink:href="#r0"/><use x="21" y="12" xlink:href="#r0"/><use x="24" y="12" xlink:href="#r0"/><use ..............much more lines </svg>
```

How can I convert this string into svg file content and download it without saving it in storage or anywhere? Is there a way for this?

I tried

```
$data = base64_decode($file);
$im = imagecreatefromstring($data);
```

but this throws `imagecreatefromstring(): Data is not in a recognized format`

Comment: SVGs are not images - why don't you just echo this data?

Comment: @NicoHaase Okay, I can echo it but I need it to download it as image, how could I do that?

Comment: Set appropriate headers and `readfile`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try outputting the image the following way:

```
header('Content-type: image/svg+xml');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=image.svg');
echo $data;
```

Comment: Thanks you, I had similar solution in AppServiceProvider to add to response, but I was sending wrong variable this answer helped me see this mistake

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your $file has the entire contents of the svg

```
return response($file)->withHeaders(['Content-Type' => "image/svg+xml"]);
```

This is something on the docs 
[1](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/responses#file-downloads) , [2](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/responses#attaching-headers-to-responses)

Comment: Thanks for the answer